# How can I delete the proper object property value in JS

Tags: javascript

I am working through a little practice assignment and have come across this question and for the life of me can't figure it out.
There are tests parameters that I can't see. The **object** is not a variable I can see, it's just assumed.

***Write a function called removePassword that takes in an object.
Delete the property password and return the object.***

```
removePassword=(object)=>{
for(var key in object){
  if(object = object[key]){
  delete object[key]
    }
  }return object;
}
```

I have tried a bunch of different versions of this code, but I don't know how to just delete the property password only without deleting the other property which is a username

Comment: `object = object[key]` you are assigning. It says to lool for 'password' you do not look for password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could it work for you?

```
removePassword = (object) => {
  delete object.password;
  return object;
}
```

Comment: This is one of those times, where I thought I had tried that, but I guess I was doing it wrong, That works!! Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at this solution. You can avoid doing the object copy if you want, it'll work anyway

```js
const removePassword = (user) => {
  const userCopy = {...user} // CREATE A COPY OF THE OBJECT
  delete userCopy.password // DELETE THE PASSWORD PROPERTY
  return userCopy // RETURN UPDATED USER
}

const testUser = {username: 'Mario', password: 'supersecret123'}

console.log(
  removePassword(testUser)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can see here [link](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_remove_property_object.asp)

That you can do it simply delete `object.password` or delete `object["password"]` :

```
const removePassword = (object) => {
  delete object.password;
  return object;
}
```